# Who is the companion of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism

In Narayaniya portion of the Shanti Parva in Mahabharata, Sri Hari tells Narada:

> Assuming a form that is manifest, I dwell, at present, in the heavens. At the end of a thousand Yugas I shall once more with-draw the universe into myself. Having withdrawn all creatures, mobile and immobile into myself, **I shall exist all alone with knowledge only for my companion.**

He is saying he alone will exist after withdrawing everything mobile or immobile into himself. So who will remain? Who is the companion mentioned?

Comment: Maybe the companion is Lakshmi?

Comment: He means that knowledge is the companion. It should have been 'knowledge only _as_ my companion'.

Comment: Lakshmi is called akshara  because she have no perishable body like us.  She will be with the lord. Lord companion forever is Lakshmi Devi.. for veda to be meaning ful after pralaya another person had to recite them that is Lakshmi devi..  BG Chp 15 purusha kshara akshara eva cha (according to madhva) all souls are called purusha

Comment: What is the Sanskrit for that verse?

Comment: BG 15.16 sloka dvavimau pursho lokae kshara Akshara Eva cha @brahmajijnasa

Comment: @Prasanna I asked Chinmay what is this verse from Narayaniya portion of the Shanti Parva in Mahabharata.

Comment: my apologies @brahmsjijnasa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is there in Gita:

> सर्वभूतानि कौन्तेय प्रकृतिं यान्ति मामिकाम्।
>
> कल्पक्षये पुनस्तानि कल्पादौ विसृजाम्यहम्।।9.7।।
>
> 9.7 O son Kunti, all the beings go back at the end of a cycle to My Prakrti. I project them forth again at the beginning of a cycle.(Tr. by Sw. Gambhirananda)

So Sri Vishnu's Prakiti is referred to in the sloka given by you as His companion.But as there is no real distinction between Shakti and Shaktimaan, or Prakiti or Purusha, He remains alone in real sense.

As Sri Ramakrishna says (Kathamrita, 27 October 1882):

> When there is no creation, Mahakali (Prakriti) is staying with Mahakaala(Purusha). One can not think of Brahman (or Purusha) independent of Shakti (Prakriti) and of Shakti (Prakriti) wthout Brahman (Purusha).

So Sri Ramakrishna also says the same thing. Purusha and Prakriti merge with one another at the time of pralaya. Sri Ramakrishna used to say that this state is 'beyond dvaita and advaita'.

**Prakriti and Purusha are non-separable from each other**.This I had discussed in my reply to another question: [How are the object and the subject one and the same?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33259/how-are-the-object-and-the-subject-one-and-the-same/33266#33266)