# Which is more powerful Prakruti or Purusha?

Tags: purusha, prakruti

I understand that both are opposite of each other and both are needed to maintain balance but if we have to select one of the two i.e Prakruti and Purusha

- Which one is more powerful and self reliant?
- Which one needs to be tamed more, I mean if let free can go out of control?

Can we conclude that if Prakruti let free can go out of control hence it needs Purusha to keep control over it or is it vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

This topic is dealt beautifully by Dr.Mahanamvrata Brahmachari, the great scholar and sadhaka from a Gaudiya Vaishnava sect in his article (Saktivaad o Mahaprabhu) :

The basis of the Vedas is the Purusha-Vaada (the Purusha-Doctrine)..

> "purusha eva idam sarvam yadbhutam jat cha bhaavyam"  (The Purusha is All of these that has been here and would be here) -- this is the basic mantra of the Purusha-vaada. This world originates from the Purusha, is preserved by the Purusha and merges with the Purusha during destruction. Prakriti is just Maya.

According to the Vedas, the Purusha is Para-Brahman.

The basis of the Tantras is Prakiti (Shakti)-Vaada (the Prakriti-Doctrine)..

> yaa devi sarvabhuteshu shakti-rupena samsthitaa (Goddess Prakriti pervades every being as Shakti)-- this is the basic mantra of the Prakriti-Vaada. Shakti is the creator, the preserver and the destroyer of the world.Purusha remains inactive as 'Shava' (Dead body).

According to the Tantras, Shakti is the Para-Brahman.

Nigama and Agama --both of the above are our gretest spiritual wisdom coming from the seers of the Truth.

The Sankhya philosophy says that Prakiti works by getting signal from the Purusha.

The Vishitadvaita philosophy says that the Purushottama is the Ultimate Truth.He is qualified by the Prakriti.

According to the Gita, the basic tattva is Purusha-Uttama, Who has two Prakritis --Paraa and Aparaa.

The reconciliation according to him is in accepting both as equally true, as according to our scriptures, they are the same though just appear as different.So Mahaprabhu says that there is difference between Purusha (Sri Krishna) and Prakriti (Sri Radhika), but their difference is unthinkable(Achintya).

Our tradition accept both as equally true and powerful as I have referred to in my other answer : [How are the object and the subject one and the same?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33259/how-are-the-object-and-the-subject-one-and-the-same/33266#33266)

So the question :who would control whom does not arise in the spiritual plane.

Reference: Chandi-Chinta, Dr.Mahanamvrata Brahmachari, Mahauddharan Math, page 148-154.